# bind_param() error when making nested mysqli call

Tags: php, mysqli

When trying to bind params i get the error: "Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in ....." These queries run fine on separate scripts but when i want to run them nested i keep getting the same error. I've tried a lot to find out how to fix it but could not.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db');
$ignore_time=time()-(24*60*60);
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare("select id,new_count from view_gallery where lastUpdate< ? and new_count >0");
$stmt->bind_param('i',$ignore_time);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($id, $count);
while($stmt->fetch())
{
    $stmt_new=$mysqli->prepare("update gallery set power=power + ? where id= ?");
    $power=$count* 0.01;
    $stmt_new->bind_param('di',$power,$id);
    $stmt_new -> execute();
}
```

The error is thrown in the bind_param line inside the loop.

Comment: The `prepare()` probably fails. The problem is likely to be the missing space in `lastUpdate<`, but you should catch errors like this in your code

Comment: the error is actually thrown in the bind_param() call inside the loop for the update call. The queries are working fine separately. Do i have to initiate the connection each time?

Comment: Is the field `power` a float/double type in the database too?

Comment: A usual answer I am giving on such questions

1. You aren't [checking for the actual errors](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php)
2. You're using mysqli, while [PDO have to be used instead.](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info)

Comment: yes it is float. And Like i have mentioned the queries themselves are fine! they work perfectly well separately. Its only when i combine them in a loop that the update fails..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was that the results of the outer loop were to be saved:

```
$stmt->store_result();
```

right above the while loop.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because your `prepare()` call is not returning a valid object. This is accounted to the fact that your SQL query is wrong.

In your query, you have `power` which is a [reserved function keyword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_power) in MySQL.

Escape it using backticks in the query and your code will work.

```
$stmt_new = $mysqli->prepare( "UPDATE gallery SET `power` = `power` + ? WHERE `id` = ?" );
```

Using backticks is always a good practice.

Comment: i added the ticks, but its not solving the problem still.

Comment: @Suyash As mentioned above in the comments, check for errors by turning the `mysqli_errors` reporting on.

Comment: trying to do echo $stmt_new->error(); but it gives me the same non-object error. Rookie for mysqli.

Comment: Use `if( !$stmt_new )    echo $mysqli->error;` before your `bind_param` call.